# Print formated code in Jupyter

Tags: python, formatting, jupyter-notebook

I have a code

```
"if x > 18:\n\tif y > 500000:\n\t\tprint('switch_credit_type')\n\telif y < 50000:\n\t\tif z > 2:\n\t\t\tprint('success')\n\t\telse:\n\t\t\tprint('get_more_info')\n\telse:\n\t\tprint('get_more_info')\nelse:\n\tprint('fail')\n"
```

Is any way to format it and print in jupyter cell like a

```
"if x > 18:
    if y > 500000:
        print('switch_credit_type')
    elif y < 50000: 
        if z > 2:
            print('success')
        else:
            print('get_more_info')
    else:
        print('get_more_info')
else:
    print('fail')"
```

Comment: Have you tried using `print`? What happened?

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you, it was stupid question